# Does Cloud Datastore support Customer Supplied Encryption Keys?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

The documentation just lists server side encryption, where Google handles the keys. Is it possible to use customer supplied keys ala Cloud Storage?

Comment: Reading the following article, my gut would say no ... you can't supply customer keys https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/encryption-at-rest

Have a read at the article and let's see if this comes close to answering the question or if it changes the flavor of the question.

Comment: yeah that is the documentation I mentioned and I suspect that is the case - I know the GCP people answer questions on here though so it would be nice for a definitive answer/make it known that this is desired feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use Customer Supplied Encryption keys, at this time, with Cloud Datastore.